# how to pass one aspx page combobox id to another aspx page in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am having two aspx page. One aspx page named is default1.aspx and another aspx page named is default2.aspx. Now, how can I pass the combobox of default1.aspx page to the default2.aspx page in asp.net c#.